# How to display data from a database w/o appending other data from another database in a JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a JComboBox that retrieves data from a database and display it in a JTable. Everything works well except that data from different databases are combined in the JTable. Do you have any idea how can I display only the data of a specific database? Thanks!

Below was the code I used.

```
  private void comBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  
  {                                       
        if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Select . . .") {   

        } else if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Students") {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();  
        String sql = "select * from students";
        try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});
        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } else if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Teachers"){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    String sql = "select * from teachers";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age");
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});

        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    } else if (comBox.getSelectedItem() == "Directors") {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
    String sql = "select * from directors";
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datavisibility","root","");
        Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rslt.next()){
            String id = rslt.getString("ID");
            String name = rslt.getString("Name");
            String surname = rslt.getString("Surname");
            String age = rslt.getString("Age"); 
            model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname,age});

        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}                                 `
```

This was the [output](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=eb81d7d0042dfe6b&resid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!165&parid=EB81D7D0042DFE6B!158&authkey=!AP4pPOBcvfh0XLU) of the program.

I will appreciate any inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling model.addRow() which will add new rows on to the existing data model. It is not clearing the data model anywhere. Hence the rows are getting appended to the previous data. You need to set the data model to a new one or delete the existing data first.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to clear the rows first as in Ashwini's answer. Take a look at this framework which makes coding ing swing easier. It has an answer for your table question. Basically you should build your model instead of using the DefaultTableModel and add additional functionality to it.

http://code.google.com/p/swingobjects/

Look at the second example in there which describes the use of the Swing Object's table model.